# How do I skip duplicate documents in a bulk insert and ignore duplicates with a specific field c#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I need to insert many documents and ignore the duplicated docs.

Doc format:

```
_id:5b84e2588aceda018a974450
Name:"Jeff M"
Email:"jeff.m@xtrastaff.com"
Type:"Client"
UserId:Binary('Rw+KMGpSAECQ3gwCtfoKUg==')
UserImage:null
```

I want to check the duplication using the *EmailId* field when I am inserting. Insert only if it is not existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the duplicates being inserted you need a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/index.html) which can be created in C# code:

```
public void CreateIndex()
{
    var options = new CreateIndexOptions() { Unique = true };
    var field = new StringFieldDefinition<Model>(nameof(Model.Email));
    var indexDefinition = new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<Model>().Ascending(field);
    Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(indexDefinition, options);
}
```

Then you can insert multiple documents using [BulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) operation. The problem is that by default the processing will be stopped when first insert operation fails (which happens when you try to insert a duplicate) and you'll get an exception in C#. You can modify that by setting `ordered` parameter to `false` which means that all the inserts will be processed "in parallel" and you'll get one exception which aggregates all failed inserts. That exception is of type `MongoBulkWriteException` and you can try to catch it. So you can try following method:

```
public void InsertData(List<Model> data)
{
    var writeOps = data.Select(x => new InsertOneModel<Model>(x));
    try
    {
        Collection.BulkWrite(writeOps, new BulkWriteOptions() { IsOrdered = false });
    }
    catch (MongoBulkWriteException ex)
    {
        // will be thrown when there were any duplicates
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi can you please help me with this question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550759/store-json-string-as-mongodb-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: @AjasAju I promise I'll take a look in the evening - have no time right now

Comment: Great,Thank you mickl